# 2sxc module won't work if change input type of a field from default to any WYSIWYG editor

Tags: wysiwyg, 2sxc

I have a customized field that is called "subTitle", the date type is "String", input type is "default". If you change "default" to any WYSIWYG editor, it will be not working, it used to be working and I could edit the content through the editor. It's not working after upgrading Dnn core from 8 to 9 or 9 above
[Default setting for subtitle works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AEty.jpg)

[It shows the content of subtitle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hztDD.jpg)

[Change default to a WYSIWYG editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OalA1.jpg)

[It shows error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL2NW.jpg)

Comment: Hi Daming Zhang! Welcome to StackOverflow. Maybe you could show us the code of this customized module? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example The better you make the question, the easier you'll make it for someone to answer it.

Comment: Hi @Daming Zhang - what you're describing should work is a very basic functionality, so it's hard to guess what could be wrong. If you could add code or in this case Screenshots that would probably help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause. It's because in very old installations, the primary App `Content` has App ID #1 which normally is reserved for system functionality.

Because of this, old input-configurations in the DB are prioritized over new ones which are in the file-system.

Just rename the input-types in the App and you should be good to go (as they are not actually used any more). I created a checklist for this: https://azing.org/2sxc/r/1yZjqy86

Comment: I Updated it to 11.11.04 and follow this https://azing.org/2sxc/r/1yZjqy86  
First, I click admin ->click Data ->choose "Scope: System:Field" ->click on "Custom Input Type Configuration" ->click on "string-wysiwyg"
Then I either try to update the type or label or both (Change to string-wysiwyg-xxx).                 
After that, I update my input type of customized field from the dropdown list to "wysiwyg editor (recommended)-xxx" 
When you edit it, it's showing "Field configuration is incomplete should be fixed".
It's showing "Missing component class for: string-wysiwyg" in the console.

Comment: Wow, an update for my comment. It will fix for wysiwyg-dnn in this way! The other wysiwyg editor still face the issue. But at least I have a working one. I'm really appreciate for your helping. Thank you so much.

Comment: thx. if it doesn't work right away, you probably forgot to restart DNN :). Best mark this as answered for others.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what happened. There are a few different WYSIWYG fields, some are leftovers of previous versions and we probably never check that they still work. Could you check that you used the `default` WYSIWYG field?

Because it could be that if you used another one, that it one cannot be found.

Comment: Hey thank you for replying. Yep I have tried every option of WYSIWYG fields, none of them is working. It will be working if I delete the 2sxc content module and install a new one. It won't be working if I just do a reinstalling.

Comment: What happens when you add a new wysiwyg field? It could somehow be that this is a very old field and may have some 2016 configuration which isn't in use any more, interfering?

Comment: I think you probably right. I've tried to install the 2sxc 11+ versions, it will show a tip, something like "the configuration is not completed" when I create a new wysiwyg field. I remember that we upgraded 8.x version 2sxc module to 10.27 version in 2020, then the issue show up. Do you know where I can update the configuration for 2sxc and how? Since we have a lot places using 2sxc, it will be great if we can fix that. Thanks again.

Comment: I'll try to help you, but we must first verify that this is the cause. Can you confirm that if you create a new wysiwyg-field, everything works?

Comment: Thank you for replying. If I create a new wysiwyg-field everything works except the new field itself.  If I drag the new wysiwyg field above existing fields, those existing fields won't show up when I am going to add a new item. I am using 10.27.1 version of 2sxc content module.

Comment: This sounds really strange. Just a quick check: what if you update to v11? Maybe everything just works then.

Comment: We just had the same scenario updating an old 2sxc. We'll probably try to fix it in the code to handle this case. If that works, we'll release today.